# Nginx reverse proxy for MySQL

Tags: mysql, nginx

I'm trying to use a reverse proxy for mysql. For some reason this doesn't work (where mysql-1.example.com points to a VM with MySQL).

```
upstream db {
    server mysql-1.example.com:3306;
}

server {
    listen 3306;
    server_name mysql.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://db;
    }
}
```

Is there a correct way to do this? I tried connecting via mysql, but doens't work

Comment: The MySQL client/server protocol doesn't use HTTP.  Whilst it is possible to (reverse) proxy the protocol, that's not something that NGINX can do (without some third party modules)—see [MySQL Proxy](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) for an alternative.  What NGINX can do for you, should you so wish, is balance the TCP streams—but that's not really "proxying" in its strictest sense: see the [TCP Load Balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/) chapter of the [NGINX Admin Guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/) for more information.

Comment: That said, if you only have one MySQL server then load balancing won't achieve anything.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 40):

Make sure your config is not held within the http { } section of nginx.conf. This config should be outside of the http {}.

```
stream {
  upstream db {
    server mysql-1.example.com:3306;
  }

  server {
    listen 3306;
    proxy_pass db;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the including of other "sites" is inside the `http{}` in `nginx.conf`, is that still acceptable?

Comment: Also please note that `stream` block must be put in the main nginx file- typically `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, not inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` folder.

Answer (score 14):

You're trying to accomplish a TCP proxy with an http proxy, which is wrong.

Nginx can do the TCP load balancing/proxy stuff but the syntax is different.

look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/ for more info

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible as of nginx 1.9 using TCP reverse proxies.
You need to compile nginx with the `--with-stream` parameter.
Then, you can add `stream` block in your config like @samottenhoff said in his answer.

For more details, see https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/ and http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html.

Answer (score -3):

Nginx plus (paid) has proper option to do that.  Another way to let the docker container access to host database directly.

Comment: Nginx plus is not required for MySQL reverse proxy. Also, the question author did not even mention if he uses docker.

Comment: @user1123432 - Yes. We do not require Nginx plus to implement reverse proxy.